# jQuery UI Dialog Error: b("<div></div>").addClass("ui-widget-overlay") is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, dialog, widget

I have the below code for my a Dialog box for a which contains a dropdown field

```
KPMS.ServiceRequests.Status = {

 showOptions : function(requestId, userId, requestType) {
  var url = BASE_URL+'service_requests/status_options/';

        $("#dialog-modal").dialog("destroy");
  $("#dialog-modal").load(url, {"request_id": requestId, "user_id": userId, "request_type":requestType}).dialog(
   {
    modal: true,
    title: "Update Status",
    buttons: {
     Cancel : function() {
      $(this).dialog('close');
     },
     Update: function() {
      alert(1);
     }
    }
   }
  );    
 }
}
```

There is an anchor tag to populate the Dialog

```
<a onclick="KPMS.ServiceRequests.Status.showOptions(9, 11, 'SR'); return false;" title="Update status" href="http://localhost/kitco/pms/#9"><img alt="[E]" title="Update" src="http://localhost/kitco/pms/images/edit.png"></a>
```

My problem is When i click the link for the first time the dialog box is populating properly.
Then I closed the dialog using the cancel button, then again clicked the link to open the dialog and closed it.
For the third click on the link I'm getting the below Javascript error, and Dialog box is not opened

```
Error: b("<div></div>").addClass("ui-widget-overlay") is undefined
Source File: http://localhost/kitco/pms/js/jquery-ui-1.8rc3.custom.min.js
Line: 199
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: You should use the un-minimized version of jQuery to help debug.  Also, try using a debugger (like firebug or the one built into IE8) that will allow you to trace the call stack.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

why do you keep destroying and rebuilding the dialog why not just build the dialog once and load/change the content of the dialog div ? I think that should solve the problem

Comment: I thought it might do the trick I tried using destroy before and found this method to be better

Answer (score 1):

Does it really say `b`? Should that not be `$` or `jQuery`?

**EDIT**: nevermind, it's an internal jQuery call, so that explains the `b`. `b` should be an alias to the `jQuery` object (`var b = this`), so that means the `div` creation is working, but that `addClass` is not / is returning `undefined`.

Are you sending your document as `application/xhtml+xml`, perchance? I have had a lot of [trouble](http://dev.jquery.com/ticket/6162) with jQuery 1.4 and jQuery UI 1.8 when using XTML, not HTML. Just a hunch.